# Count completed events at the start of the next event

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

I've got a dataset that measures events that last multiple days (event_start to event_end) for multiple individuals (id).  I want to count the number of completed events at the date of the next event.  I can do this via iterrows however this is very slow at scale.  Can you help me reduce the run time?

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'id': 1, 'event_start': '2020-01-01', 'event_end': '2020-01-03'},
{'id': 1, 'event_start': '2020-01-02', 'event_end': '2020-01-04'},
{'id': 1, 'event_start': '2020-01-03', 'event_end': '2020-01-05'},
{'id': 1, 'event_start': '2020-01-07', 'event_end': '2020-01-10'},
{'id': 2, 'event_start': '2020-01-06', 'event_end': '2020-01-07'},
{'id': 2, 'event_start': '2020-01-08', 'event_end': '2020-01-10'},])
df['event_start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['event_start'])
df['event_end'] = pd.to_datetime(df['event_end'])
df = df.sort_values(['id', 'event_start', 'event_end'])

for index, row in df.iterrows():
   df.at[index, 'Previous Count'] = df[(df['id'] == row['id']) & (df['event_end'] < row['event_start'])].count()[0]

df
```

Answer (score 0):

I compared these two strategies

First yours

```
%time
df = pd.DataFrame([{'id': 1, 'event_start': '2020-01-01', 'event_end': '2020-01-03'},
{'id': 1, 'event_start': '2020-01-02', 'event_end': '2020-01-04'},
{'id': 1, 'event_start': '2020-01-03', 'event_end': '2020-01-05'},
{'id': 1, 'event_start': '2020-01-07', 'event_end': '2020-01-10'},
{'id': 2, 'event_start': '2020-01-06', 'event_end': '2020-01-07'},
{'id': 2, 'event_start': '2020-01-08', 'event_end': '2020-01-10'},])
df['event_start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['event_start'])
df['event_end'] = pd.to_datetime(df['event_end'])
df = df.sort_values(['id', 'event_start', 'event_end'])

for index, row in df.iterrows():
   df.at[index, 'Previous Count'] = df[(df['id'] == row['id']) & (df['event_end'] < row['event_start'])].count()[0]

df
```

and I got

```
CPU times: user 2 µs, sys: 0 ns, total: 2 µs
Wall time: 5.01 µs
```

Then I tried using groupby to cut the iterrows down to just in the same id.  I am unsure if this will be faster unless the dataframes are big, as the set up time will be quite a bit more.

```
%time
df = pd.DataFrame([{'id': 1, 'event_start': '2020-01-01', 'event_end': '2020-01-03'},
{'id': 1, 'event_start': '2020-01-02', 'event_end': '2020-01-04'},
{'id': 1, 'event_start': '2020-01-03', 'event_end': '2020-01-05'},
{'id': 1, 'event_start': '2020-01-07', 'event_end': '2020-01-10'},
{'id': 2, 'event_start': '2020-01-06', 'event_end': '2020-01-07'},
{'id': 2, 'event_start': '2020-01-08', 'event_end': '2020-01-10'},])
df['event_start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['event_start'])
df['event_end'] = pd.to_datetime(df['event_end'])
df = df.sort_values(['id', 'event_start', 'event_end'])

outdf = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)
for id, subdf in df.groupby('id'):
    for index, row in subdf.iterrows():
        subdf.at[index, 'Previous Count'] = subdf[(subdf['event_end'] < row['event_start'])].count()[0]
    outdf = pd.concat([outdf,subdf])

outdf
```

and I got

```
CPU times: user 2 µs, sys: 1 µs, total: 3 µs
Wall time: 5.96 µs
```

Your milage will vary depending on the size and make up of your big dataframe, but worth a try.